# Posting to Instagram via Script/Online/Program. Anything is good but mobile

Tags: instagram

I just wanted to know if there is a way to upload images to Instagram WITHOUT using iOS / Android?

I'm really desperate for a solution, if I can't find anything I will have to run a virtual android device or something like that (I have a virtual machine running Windows XP 24/7 anyway)!

Answer (score 3):

Instagram's official RESTful API does not allow for uploading photos, since they want to encourage "life on the go."

However, some work has been put together to document their iPhone API, and some unofficial client libraries have even been made.  Check out https://github.com/mislav/instagram/wiki

It seems that's your only alternative at the moment.  None of the unofficial libraries look very complete, so you'd have to do the work of sending requests manually, using the reverse-engineered API specs provided in the wiki.

Comment: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

_At this time, uploading via the API is not possible._

Comment: You are correct.  I've edited my above answer to show the work done to reverse their mobile API to allow any web client to use it.

Comment: Okay well that looks promising but also complicated! I'll try and work out a script that does exactly what I want. If someone finds a script that already does this, please tell me :)