# Uploading Images To Instagram Programmatically

Tags: c#, instagram

this question is for people that have experience with Instagram. I want to create an application that uploads a set of images to Instagram, but I have never used their API.

I want to know if it is possible to upload images through the API, and if it's not, is there an alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

```
At this time, uploading via the API is not possible.
```

So no.

This question is also answered here:

[Posting to Instagram via Script/Online/Program. Anything is good but mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617586/posting-to-instagram-via-script-online-program-anything-is-good-but-mobile)

Comment: Dang. But then how to the apps upload their images? Is there an unofficial API you think?